# What is the proper angular keycloak version to use with keycloak server 12.0.4 while I have angular 10 in my application

Tags: angular, keycloak

I am running in a Kubernetes environment What is the proper angular keycloak version to use with keycloak server 12.0.4 while I have angular 10 in my application?

I was using angular adapter 7~ when the keycloak version was 8.0.1 after upgrading to 12.0.4 It is still working but wandered if I should upgrade and to what version.

tried 8.0.3 and I am seeing odd behavior, keycloak adapter getUsername function stopped working, saying user info was not loaded.

Comment: That is a good question but not a good fit for stack overflow unfortunately.

Comment: Plus it doesn't have anything to do with kubernetes.

Answer (score 1):

As per angular-keycloak here is the version matrix https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular#readme

Versions

```
Angular       keycloak-angular   keycloak-js     Support
------------|------------------|---------------|----------------|
11.x - 12.x   8.3.x              10 - 14         Bugs / New Features
10.x          8.x.x              10 - 11         Bugs
9.x           7.3.x              3.4.3 - 10      Bugs
                                 (excluding v7)
```

In your case, you have to base it on keycloak-js version being used. For keycloak-js version greater than 11, you should use angular-keycloak 8.3.0 or greater.

8.1.0 is the closest one for you for the combination (Angular-10 with keycloak 12.0.4)

Comment: There is no matching version of 8.3.x for keycloak-angular is available.

Comment: 8.3.0 and 8.4.0 both available. https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular/v/8.3.0 If you are using `npm` you can install it using command `npm install keycloak-angular@8.3.0`